# Can I allow hyphen in URLs using htaccess for dynamically loaded pages?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm creating a forum, and after sanitizing the slugs I want them to look like so for the url slug `this-is-my-thread-09-10-16-6-18pm`, I have everything called from the index.php file and it simply rewrites the urls. Is there anyway to allow the - to be used in the dynamic call? Right now they simply return a 404 error.
My current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?ident=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?ident=$1&ident2=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?ident=$1&ident2=$2&ident3=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?ident=$1&ident2=$2&ident3=$3&ident4=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?ident=$1&ident2=$2&ident3=$3&ident4=$4&ident5=$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?ident=$1&ident2=$2&ident3=$3&ident4=$4&ident5=$5&ident6=$6 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?ident=$1&ident2=$2&ident3=$3&ident4=$4&ident5=$5&ident6=$6&ident7=$7 [L,QSA]


php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w` is a [PCRE regex](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) base class for `(a-z 0-9 _)`. It doesn't match hyphen `-` characters. Only letters from `a` to `z`, number characters from `0` through `9` and **underscore** characters `_`. You will need to specify the hyphen yourself using `[a-z0-9-]+`. Unless you also want the underscore in there.

Comment: Added the `[a-z0-9-]+` on the identifier where the posts name would be and it works just like I wanted. The .htaccess was a friend helping me years ago that I've just held onto. I've always assumed \w included + and -, Thanks for the reminder that I need to reread on htaccess rules even if I hate them. =D

Comment: Done. Very informative; Sorry; stack wasn't letting me mark it at first.